# Google Places API - Place Searches - Phone Number

Tags: google-places-api

Based on the documentation it would appear that there is no way to have the phone numbers for a google place to be returned with the Place Search data ?

Which means that if I do a Place Search request  I then need to make 20 more "Place Details" requests to get the phone number for each search result.

To mean this seems like a a fundamental piece of information I would expect back from the 
"Place Search" request ?

Am I missing something or or is there no way or getting the phone numbers returned based on a search request ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is correct, there is no way to get the phone number of a business without issuing a Place Details request.

This is in place to encourage compliance with [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) - [Section 10.2 Restrictions on the Types of Applications that You are Permitted to Build with the Maps API(s)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_2): (b) No Business, Residential, or Telephone Listings Services.

You should only need to issue a Places Details request if a user action indicates that they would like more information about a Place.